# Neo4j var-length path search slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-ogm, neo4j-apoc

I intend to retrieve all incoming nodes, whose closest distance is less than N, to a specific node via `match (c:Column {schema:'a.b', name:'c'})<-[cd:CD*1..3]-(c_up:Column) return c, cd, c_up`, it virtually takes approx. 8s to return all the results. I tried to profile it via `profile {sql}` and this it what it returns:

https://i.ibb.co/fYbD2vn/WX20190326-145433-2x.png (the image paste in stackoverflow crashes in my current case, so i pasted to another host)

I've created index via `CREATE INDEX ON :Column(schema, name)`, but it doesn't help any to the execution plan of var-length path search. Any ideas to optimize the immense db hits at `VarLengthExpand` and `Filter`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I've created index via CREATE INDEX ON :Column(schema, name), but it doesn't help any to the execution plan of var-length path search.

Your index does not directly help the `varlengthexpand` but actually help speed up your query a lot. (Look at the first operation, `NodeIndexSeeker`, it returns only 2 matches)

For your use case:

> I intend to retrieve all incoming nodes, whose closest distance is less than N,

I think return `cd` is a waste, and you can use `distinct` to avoid returning a node `c_up` twice.

There's an example in the frontpage: [DISTINCT nodes from variable-length paths](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-cypher-cardinality/)
:

```
MATCH (c:Column {schema:'a.b', name:'c'})<-[cd:CD*1..3]-(c_up:Column) 
RETURN DISTINCT c, c_up
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Even if i added `DISTINCT` to cypher query, the first two step (`varlengthexpand` and `filter`) is the same as the previous one, since the distinct is being inserted after the `filter` step, which doesn't help much to this scenario. Any more suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: In the latest versions it will then use a different type (pruning-var-length-expand) which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not so much the query which looks quite **tiny**, but:

1. returning 6000 nodes to the neo4j browser visualization (and many more relationships
2. use a dedicated client to fetch the data or check cypher-shell
3. check your memory config it might be that it has to fetch things from disk (page-cache and heap settings)

Comment: Hey, I checked `:sysinfo`, the page cache is with 100% Hit Ratio and 1.52% Usage Ratio, and the memory is allocated by neo4j itself without hardcoded. and it's confirmed that neo4j literally takes quite some memory (44GB and 21GB respectively per HA node). So is there any more suggestions for this case? Thanks a lot